# Were the rest of the Treasures of Rule ever found?

Tags: the-pirates-of-dark-water

In the cartoon *Pirates of Dark Water* the crew of the Wraith were searching for the 13 Treasures of Rule to cleanse the waters of Mer of the titular Dark Water.  Over the course of the series only 8 were found before the show was cancelled.

Was there any word of what the other five were, or any other sources (comic, videogame) that showed the Ren and others finding the other treasures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As best I can tell, they were never described, and it's possible that they were never decided. [This site](http://piratesofdarkwater.net/buriedtreasure/) has the comic, which covered the first five episodes and a side story so there are no new treasures, the RPG, which only [mentions them as an aside](http://piratesofdarkwater.net/buriedtreasure/worldbook/26.html) and says that the MP should decide what they are, and the [Series Bible](http://piratesofdarkwater.net/buriedtreasure/seriesbible.html), which only covers the first (and only) season, does not describe them further. Interestingly enough, the [interview with Kirchner](http://piratesofdarkwater.net/buriedtreasure/washpost-kirschner.html) around the time the show premiered indicated that the "treasures" were originally intended to be "qualities such as perseverance, strength, grace, generosity, kindness" that would make Ren an able ruler rather than the actual objects.

The fact that the Series Bible does not contain the treasures suggests to me that they were not yet decided, and that they would have been established as the series went on.